# create boost tool executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost

I want to know how to create a tool executable, for example bcp, with the boost libraries. I have unzip the sources, but I do not know how to build to create the tool.

Thanks

Comment: Boost is a series of libraries that you use in your C++ code. You use #include directives to add the necessary Boost headers to your .cpp files, and then use the Boost functionality you need in your application's code. You then compile that code with your C++ compiler to build an executable or DLL. Voting to close as "not a real question".

Answer (score 20):

Complementing hkaiser answer:

Run `./bootstrap.sh` from `$BOOST_ROOT` (refer to [Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/index.html) for additional options)

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

This will generate the a `./bjam` executable. You may then do

```
./bjam tools/bcp
```

Or even copy this executable to `tools/bcp` and do

```
./bjam
```

The `./bcp` executable will be in `$BOOST_ROOT/dist/bin`

Answer (score 3):

All tools in the directory $BOOST_ROOT/tools can be build by invoking `bjam` from the directory where the corresponding `Jamfile[.v2]` is located. For bcp this needs to be done in the directory $BOOST_ROOT/tools/bcp. If you have not built bjam yet, please refer to the [Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/index.html) document explaining the necessary steps. The built executable by default will end up in $BOOST_ROOT/dist/bin.